# Web File Uploader that supports selecting entire directory structures

Tags: web-applications, file-upload, multifile-uploader

Would you guys give me an advice?

I need to build an uploader with UI where user would be able to choose not only one file or multiple files but also entire directories (to upload their content)

Is there any way to do it without using any java applets, Silverlight or Flash apps?

I guess HTML5 FileSystem API won't do. It works only in a sandbox, whereas I'm gonna need to access all directories on the disk. (I might be wrong)

Is there any way to tweak "Select File dialog" to make it able to select directories (on Win-PC) and folders (on Mac). (At this point I don't really care about Unix - only Windows and Mac)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, sorry. You need to use Flash or Java to access the real local filesystem.

Comment: It can too - but try convincing users to install it.